# How to break sequence handlers of Promises/A?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How to break sequence of handlers of Promises/A?

## For example

if we have sequence:

```
method1().then(method2())
         .then(method3(), errorHandler3());
```

and in *method2()* we decided to break sequence and don't go farther nor to *method3()* or *errorHandler3()*. What we should do?

Comment: You shouldn't initialize your function if they doesn't return another. (`then(method2())` -> `then(method2)`?)

Comment: Are you sure the `method2`, `method3` and `errorHandler3` functions are invoked there (instead of being passed as handlers)?

Comment: @Bergi If you are asking to my comment above, then Yes..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a promise that never is resolved from the function that `method2()` yields.

However, that doesn't make much sense, as "*breaking the sequence*" means going to error state actually, and should be possible to handle.

Maybe you rather want

```
method1().then(function method2(res) {
    // do something
    if (/* you want to break*/)
        throw new Error("reason for breaking");
    else
        return when(/* what is done */).then(method3(), errorHandler3());
});
```

Comment: Yeah, *never-resolved-promises* can solve issue. But it's seem more like *stuck-forever* that's definitely lead to memory leaks.

Comment: But *breaking-the-sequence* is *stuck-forever*? Not sure why you would want that. Btw, the promise that is never resolved should be garbage-collectable as there's nothing held in memory that can resolve it.

Comment: Yes, - *throw exception* can be a key if Promises can deals with such issues.

Comment: to *use never-resolved-promises* we need to return it from *method2()* so it will be locked by sequenced Promises.

Comment: What do you mean by "can deal with"? Promise/A-compliant implementations are specified to do. And what do you mean by "locked"? If nothing references the promise chain, it will get collected.

Comment: By the way I think in your answer we don't even need to throw exception - because if all farther sequnce of *then-handler-functions* going after *else*, it will never involve in *throw-exception section*.

Comment: about *locking*:

I mean that we need to return *Promise* that we are never going to resolve If we want that other Promises waiting for method2(). So if we have returned Promise from method2() all farther sequence of handlers will lock-on it.

Comment: any way it's seem that *if-else conditional* doesn't provided in Promises and in such case we need to break sequence of Promises in two pieces. ( method1() -> method2() and method2() -> method3()+errorHandler3() )

Comment: Well, you still have a sequence of promises - the outer `then` also returns one. It's up to `method2` to dynamically either reject it (by `throw`ing) or the resolve it with the `method3`-chained promise.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you should nest your logic in a callback passed to then, e.g.

```
method1().then(function (value) {
  if (method2(value)) return method3();
}).done();
```

I simplified my example, so it doesn't take callbacks from other function calls (as it is in your code). It looks a bit weird, and definitely is not common in promises world, what is your reasoning behind it?

Commenting on other solution, you definitely should not use promise that *never resolves*. In well written logic all promises resolve, and if there are ones that doesn't it means you have a  bug in your logic (it's like creating async function that is never meant to call a callback, doesn't make sense).